# KMM Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile Error: Could not detect version of installed Xcode

Tags: android, xcode, android-studio, kmm

I was gonna try KMM on my machine.

When I trying to run the initialization app "Hello World" on android, it's fine. But when I run it on iOS, there's a problem.

I got Xcode ver 13.1 installed on my machine, before I install the Android Studio.

I Couldn't find any answer on the internet.

I've tried to reinstall my Android Studio, but it did nothing

[image: pic]

Answer (score 3):

Try to type

```
xcode-select -p
```

on your Terminal.

make sure your terminal reply with

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

if not, you have to change it,
type this on your Terminal

```
xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

that's it.